# What is the way to mearge two arrays even duplicate values exists?

Tags: php, arrays

```
    sele_itmid =
    Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 6
    )
    $recp_qty =
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 16
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 10
    )
    //when i tried using 
    $comine = array_combine($sele_itmid,$recp_qty);
   print_r($comine);exit();
am getting a result like

Array
(
    [1] => 16
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 10
)

what i actually want is 
[1]=>4
[1] => 16
[5] => 1
[6] => 10
```

If possible some one Please explain why array_combine neglecting it!!

after getting an array what i actually want need to sum values of same keys

Comment: how can i sum if i has a array like $array = [1 => [4, 16], ...]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"why array_combine neglecting it?" - an array doesn't allow duplicate keys.
Here is a simple solution using `array_map` function (it will sum up the values of the same keys):

```
$result = [];

array_map(function($key, $b) use (&$result){
    (isset($result[$key]))? $result[$key] += $b : $result[$key] = $b;
}, $sele_itmid, $recp_qty);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 20
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as though you'd want to just map the two arrays together:

```
function sum($v1, $v2) {
    return $v1 + $v2;
}
$result = array_map('sum', $sele_itmid, $recp_qty);
```

Comment: @mureinik.Thanks for your time Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In here $sele_itmid 's values are used as the key of $comine  array. Since an array can not have duplicate keys first value is rejected.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?